# JavaScript: Adding & Removing objects from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var layers = {};

//Add new layer
layer.markers = new L.Group();
layer.Name = t;

layers.layer = layer;
```

Gives an error layers.length is still 'undefined'. Why is it doing that ? I have verified in log that layers contains an item.

Comment: `layers` is not an array - it's a generic object, and objects have no `length`

Comment: Also where is L defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layers` is not an array. If you want to keep it as an object literal, and check if it's empty, try defining something like this:

```
Object.isEmpty = function(obj) {
    for (var p in obj)
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) return false;
    return true;
};
```

And use

```
if (!Object.isEmpty(layers)) { ...
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're not adding to the array. The last line should be:

```
layers.push(layer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple question. **layers is an object not an array**.

What you needs to do is replace layers to following.

```
var layers = new Array();
```

And replace adding layer code from

```
layers.layer = layer;
```

to

```
layers.push(layer);
```